# Data Report and Grouping (Shape Append)

Tags: vb6

I hard-coded a data report's DataMember and Datafields (I'm not using a DataEnviroment, and don't know how either. I'd rather code it personally) but the more I check the code, I can't get to solve this thing.

The error message I'm getting is:

> Error '8526' Can't find DataField 'Omisions.Date'

in this part of the code:

> rpt.Refresh

Just before I do a `rpt.Show` at the end of the code. `rpt` is my current datareport.
Here's the relevant code:

```
  sql = "Shape {exec Usp_HoraExtra_Rut 1} As Normal " _
  & "Append ({exec Usp_HoraExtra_Rut 2} As Omisions " _
  & "Relate Nit To Nit)"
  rptrs.Open sql, db, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

I'm using two stored procedures instead because of the large queries.

Then I add the DataMember:

```
.Sections("Section1").Controls.Item("t_fecha").DataMember = "Omisions"
```

and then the DataFields:

```
.Sections("Section1").Controls.Item("t_fecha").DataField = "date"
```

and then:

```
rpt.Refresh
rpt.Show
```

If anyone can give me a hand, it'd be greatly apreciated.

Edit: typo, cleaned up the code.

Comment: Also, I forgot to add that `Nit` field is in both the stored procs queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might read this...
I solved this problem by switching from stored procs to views. For some reason SHAPE doesn't work with sotred procs and I refuse to code a big giant SQL query. I just created a view on my database and query'd it.

Also, the connnection string needs changing.
All in all, hard nut.